How to get the request tag in flask to work
For the past hour I have been trying to make the request tag work in flask..
this is my code in server.py:
@app.route('/login', methods=['post'])
def receive_data():
    user = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    return f'<h1>name:{user} password:{password}</h1>'

and in index.html its:
    <form action="{{ url_for('receive_data'}}" method="POST">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="username">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit">Ok</button>
    </form>

I also tried the request.form.get('username') but it returns none

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

better create minimal working code so we could copy and run it. At this moment code looks OK. I can only suggest to use print(request.form) to see what you really have in variable. Maybe there is some typo.

you can test code with other web browser or using console tools like curl. Maybe all problem is web browser or system.

I think you need to update the function definition part like this:
@app.route('/login',method=['post'])
def receive_data(request):

Make sure to import the request object:
from flask import Flask, request

Hehe's the server.py:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    user = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    print(user)
    print(password)
    if user and password:
        return f'<h1>Name: {user}, Password: {password}</h1>'
    else:
        return '<h1>Missing username or password</h1>', 400
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Here's the HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('receive_data') }}" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Do not forget to install Flask !
pip install Flask

Updated for debugging .

Sorry this is my first time posting a question.. i did import request from flask. i copied your code and the "Missing username or password shows up". Does this code work for you?

Clear the browser cache, just in case. Added some debugging print() to the answer. Run the code again and comment the output.

tried it this morning and now works without a problem, i dont know why but thanks a lot.
